# custom field in yii2 without generator and using database

Tags: dynamic, yii2, gii

how to add custom fields in Yii-2.i have table user ,there i have fields and creating form with but later user can add custom fields so how i create those fields in view without generator.

Answer (score 0):

1. create a migration to add the fields to the DB
2. modify your model and add the fields at the top so IDE would show them in the autocomplete, put them in the rules() and attributes() functions
3. add them to the seach model as needed
4. use them in the view.

I usually use Gii just to see what I need to add and where, you do not have to actually generate the files, you can use the diff part to see what has been added and add things by hand in case you modified the model / views already.